# Pre request script generate json request body Postman

Tags: json, api, postman

This thing I have stored the response in one variable.

"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"maths}"

I want to update the subject value as English

"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"English}"

Test script request 1:

```
var response=JSON.parse(responseBody};
Pm.globals.set("variable",JSON.stringify(response);
```

In the pre-request script for request 2:

```
var request=JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("variable"));
pm.globals.set("req_body",JSON.stringify(request));
```

In the body:

```
{{req_body}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This thing I have stored the response in one variable.

    "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"maths}"

I want to update the subject value as English                                                 "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"English}"

Test script request 1:

    var response=JSON.parse(responseBody};
    Pm.globals.set("variable",JSON.stringify(response);

In the pre-request script for request 2:

    var request=JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("variable"));
    pm.globals.set("req_body",JSON.stringify(request));

In the body: 
{{req_body}}